# Scrape info of companies on Fortune 500

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape company info from http://fortune.com/fortune500 for my thesis. As I downloaded the web_text from the link, there were no links for parsing. However, opening the link on Chrome will automatically lead to #1 company page.

Could someone kindly help explain to me what happened and how I can trace the links to company page from the original url?

Comment: This is a dynamically loading website.  You're not going to get all of the companies upon loading the text from the link.

Comment: Thank you Krono for the comment. I just found out the same. I am searching for the Fortune 500 list with company details. Would you have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the `postid`, then make a request to `/data/franchise-list`, then get the url from the first article:

```
import json
import re
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urlparse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = urlopen('http://fortune.com/fortune500/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
postid = next(attr for attr in soup.body['class'] if attr.startswith('postid'))
postid = re.match(r'postid-(\d+)', postid).group(1)

url = "http://fortune.com/data/franchise-list/{postid}/1/".format(postid=postid)
data = json.load(urlopen(url))

resulting_url = urljoin(url, data['articles'][0]['url'])
print resulting_url
```

Prints:

```
http://fortune.com/fortune500/wal-mart-stores-inc-1/
```